# Custom Fields in UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, custom-controls

We would like to add the Custom Fields Like functionality just like the Address book as displayed in the Picture like the Add New Address and Add new Field.

Using the UITableView what will be the best way to achieve this functionality, if some one can point out to a sample that will be much better.

[image: Sample]

Comment: Create a custom cell of your own and make subclass of UItableview's CELL class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve such functionality you have to create different type of `custom cell` according to your need and then while calling **CellForRowAtIndexPath** you can set the cell to your custom cell, and also you can add new cell and delete the cell from tableview by using **tableview Edit  method**. 
To add new row simply add a  new value in the data source and reload the tableview and new row will be added to the table.